# `FinancialData` anomaly

Tags: finance, curated-data

As I learned from this [quantitative finance question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/70734/why-are-there-missing-prices-for-1981-04-17?noredirect=1#comment104291_70734), 1981-04-17 was a trading holiday. This is in agreement with the 0 volume in that day

```
  "Volume", {"1981-04-17", "1981-04-17"}]["Values"]
```

gives `{Quantity[0, "Shares"]}`

However looking at the (close) prices, via

```
DateListPlot[
 FinancialData["NASDAQ:AAPL", "Close", {"1981-04-10", "1981-04-20"}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

I see an abnormally large move
[image]

Would love to know why Mathematica gives such a high price on a non-trading day. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Possible Reasons

It might be because Mathematica does not know that `"1981-04-17"` is a non-trading day when building the dataset.

```
BusinessDayQ[DateObject["1981-04-17"],HolidayCalendar->"UnitedStates"] (*True*)
BusinessDayQ[DateObject["1981-04-17"],HolidayCalendar->{"UnitedStates","NYSE"}] (*True*)
BusinessDayQ[DateObject["1981-04-17"],HolidayCalendar->{"UnitedStates","NASDAQ"}] (*True*)
```

Or it might be an error from an old dataset that Mathematica acquired.

---

### Examples of another anomalous data

It is interesting to note that `"IBM"` has a price even though it didn't trade, whilst `"GE"` is unaffected.

```
FinancialData["IBM", "OHLCV", {"1981-04-10", "1981-04-20"}] // Normal
FinancialData["GE", "OHLCV", {"1981-04-10", "1981-04-20"}] // Normal
```

[image: 17 April anomaly]

Some firms have workflows to find and correct these errors in their datasets. Either through user submission or algorithmically. For example, [Yahoo Finance](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=355708800&period2=356659200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true) does not have this error.

---

### Data Cleaning

This highlights the importance of having a process to clean and sanity-check any data we work with. For example, we can filter to select only days where `"Volume"` is larger than zero. From there we can create a new `TimeSeries` that handles missing dates by using the value of the previous date (to avoid introducing lookahead bias to the dataset). This can be done with the option `ResamplingMethod` ie `TimeSeries[cleanedData, ResamplingMethod-> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}]`.

First, we need to convert FinancialData into something we can easily manipulate.
Using the workflow for converting `FinancialData` into a flat list of assoications from my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274039/60568):

```
(*helper function*)
joinColumnToData[column_?VectorQ,data_?VectorQ]:=Transpose@{column,data};
joinColumnToData[column_?VectorQ,data_?MatrixQ]:=ArrayFlatten@{{List/@column,data}};

(*helper function*)
Options[convertFinancialDataToFlatDatePath]={"DateConversionFunction"->Function[{date},DateString[date,"ISODate"]]};
convertFinancialDataToFlatDatePath[timeSeries_TemporalData,OptionsPattern[]]:=Module[{datesRaw,valuesRaw,dates,values},datesRaw=timeSeries["Dates"];
valuesRaw=timeSeries["Values"];
dates=OptionValue["DateConversionFunction"]/@datesRaw;
values=QuantityMagnitude@valuesRaw;
joinColumnToData[dates,values]];

(* set data universe *)
tickers={"AAPL","IBM","GE"};
dataStart=DateString["1981-04-10","ISODate"];
dataEnd=DateString["1981-04-20","ISODate"];

tickerProperties="OHLCV";
tickerPropertiesHeader={"Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"};(*change if using something other than "OHLCV"*)
headers={"Ticker","Date"}~Join~tickerPropertiesHeader;

(*get list of TimeSeries from Mathematica*)
financialDataRaw=FinancialData[tickers,tickerProperties,{dataStart,dataEnd}];

(*format it*)
financialDataFlat=convertFinancialDataToFlatDatePath/@financialDataRaw;

(*add Tickers to the data*)
tickerArray=MapThread[ConstantArray[#1,#2["PathLength"]]&,{tickers,financialDataRaw}];
financialDataWithTickers=MapThread[joinColumnToData,{tickerArray,financialDataFlat}];

financialData=Map[AssociationThread[headers,#]&,financialDataWithTickers,{2}]//Flatten;
```

Secondly, we determine the steps we are going to use to clean and sanity check the raw data. In this case we select only days with positive trading volume.

```
(*data cleaning*)
financialDataClean = Select[financialData, #Volume > 0 &];
```

Finally, we convert the clean data into a new `TimeSeries` object, letting the `TimeSeries` function handle the missing dates we removed.

```
dataByDate=Values/@Query[GroupBy[#Date&],#[[All,{"Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"}]]&]@financialDataClean;
formatDataForTimeSeries=Transpose[{Keys@dataByDate,Values@dataByDate}];

cleanTimeSeries =
 TimeSeries[
  formatDataForTimeSeries,
  ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0},
  MetaInformation -> {"ComponentNames" -> tickers}
  ];
```

Also note that formatting the TimeSeries data in this way *allows us to make use of the `MetaInformation` option to call the TimeSeries we want by ticker*.

This is incredibly useful functionality when dealing with multiple assets.

```
cleanTimeSeries["PathComponent", "AAPL"]["1981-04-16"]
cleanTimeSeries["PathComponent", "AAPL"]["1981-04-17"]
cleanTimeSeries["PathComponent", "AAPL"]["1981-04-20"]

(* 
{0.111607, 0.112168, 0.111607, 0.111607, 106600.}
{0.111607, 0.112168, 0.111607, 0.111607, 106600.}
{0.114957, 0.115514, 0.114957, 0.114957, 157800} 
*)
```